# How to show the visitors content of something.com/view.php?id=myid, when the user enters something.com/myid as the url

Tags: php, apache, url, iis, webserver

How to show the visitors content of something.com/view.php?id=myid, when the user enters something.com/myid as the url?
Please note that I don't want the url to change visually in front of the users.
I found some solutions for apache but I guess the clients require IIS.
Let me know the solution for apache as well, in case you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the .htaccess file.
Take a look [here](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html)

Edit:
Didn't noticed you mentioned IIS.
Look [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig) in order to translate .htaccess to the Web.Config file.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Though I don't have enough reputation to vote you up. I'll certainly do that once I can.
Thanks again. :)

Comment: One more thing. For my requirements, this seems to be the solution.
But I want this to happen for only a certain folder or path.
E.g something.php/thisfolder/user.php?id=myid should map to something.php/thisfolder/myid.
Could you help me out in this.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^thisfolder/([0-9]+)$ user.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^thisfolder/([0-9]+)/$ user.php?id=$1

Comment: Can you please translate it for IIS? I can't figure it out.

Comment: <rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Rewrite">
<match url="^thisfolder/([0-9]+)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="thisfolder/user.php?id={R:1}" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>

Comment: Sorted it out. Actually the ids can be non-numeric as well, so [0-9]was causing the problem.
Btw how can one allow all the permissible characters, instead of just numbers and alphabets?

Answer (score 1):

Mod-rewrite will solve your problem